# Regex to find DAOs in for loops

Tags: java, regex

I am currently refactoring a program that coded by someone else.
I want to `find all DAOs inside for loops` and change each to a one-time DB access if possible.

I have tried the follwing regex but it cannot exactly find what I wanted. It only searches for loops followed by DAOs.

```
for\s*\((.*\r\n)*?.*dao
```

It helps me to fix DAOs manually but there are still too many codes remaining.

What is a regex to find DAOs in for loops?

**UPDATE**

Here is an example.

```
for (String userId : userIds) {
    User user = UserDao.select(userId);
    System.out.println(user);
}
```

Comment: Could you post some examples of strings you want to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
for\s+\(.*?\)\s*\{.*?dao.*?\}
```

Be sure to turn on the `dotall` flag, so `.` can match also newlines. Test it [here](http://regex101.com/r/dQ0cN2/1).